# Passing dynamic value gets failed in Mongodb using java script

Tags: mongodb

I have to copy the data from one collection to another collection based on a date. Here date is calculated as yesterday date dynamically and working properly.

If i pass the dynamic date value as /$yesterday/ to mongo find method, Its getting failed.

Assume data_timestamp format is 2013-08-20 17:04:40.633 and trying to get the result by like query.

Sample JS Code:

```
db=db.getSiblingDB('masterdb')

$today = new Date();

$yesterday = new Date($today);

$yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);

var $dd = $yesterday.getDate();

var $mm = $yesterday.getMonth()+1; 

var $yyyy = $yesterday.getFullYear();

if($dd<10){$dd='0'+dd} if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm} $yesterday = $yyyy+'-'+$mm+'-'+$dd;

db.mastercollection.find( { "data_timestamp": /$yesterday/ } ).forEach( function(x){db.newcollection.insert(x)} );
```

Is any other way to pass dynamic value without using '$' symbol?

Please share your valuable comments

Thanks in advance...

Ramesh Kasi

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing your query now, I'm pretty sure that `/$yesterday/` is being interpreted as a regular expression matching strings starting with "yesterday". A better approach would be to use the [`$regex` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/#regex) so that you can pass in a javascript variable that holds the regular expression you hope to match.